# Potential leak of an object - Memory Error

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks

I got memory error while analyzing the project.

The function is to check the given URL is referred to an Image URL.

> 1. Call to function 'UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag' returns a Core Foundation object of type CFStringRef _Nullable with a +1 retain
>      count
> 2. Object leaked: object allocated and stored into 'UTI' is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1

**Code:**

```
-(BOOL)isValidImageURL:(NSString *) strURL{
        strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", ROOT_BASE_URL, strURL];
        NSString * UTI = (__bridge NSString *)UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension,(__bridge CFStringRef)[[NSURL URLWithString: strURL] pathExtension],NULL);
        BOOL value = UTTypeConformsTo((__bridge CFStringRef)UTI, kUTTypeImage);
        return value;
    }
```

XCode shows Memory error on analyze. Does anyone know why it shows an error? Should I release UTI object after getting the boolean value? (If so, then how to release that object?)

Comment: It looks like you forgot to ask a question! Could you edit your post to include one?

Comment: Question updated. Please check @Alex. I don't know why XCode shows memory error.